# Не отображается главная страница с мобильного устройства

Tags: wordpress

Ситуация следующая. Установил на сайт плагин Jetpack и включил функцию адаптивного сайта. Все ок, кроме одного. Главная страница у меня построена чисто на   Content builder'e.

Из-за чего с мобильного устройства главная отображается просто как пустая запись. Есть вариант обойти это?

Comment: А выложен ли проект в сеть?... Можно ли глянуть на живом присмере?

Comment: @Keyl.in 193land.com

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, то на вашем сайте используется AMP (для оптимизации контента под моб. устройства). Вам нужно создать шаблон главной страницы для AMP. Ну и судя по всему, не только для главной, AMP работает у вас только в постах, страницы - пустые.
А вот если в футере нажать "Переглянути цілий сайт", то хомяк (главная страница / Home page) грузится нормально

Comment: Для оптимизации используется Jetpack . К сожалению, там вроде нет ( или не вижу) возможности создать шаблон главной для моб. устройств.